# How to navigate components using physical switch control (accessibility) on Android?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to develop a chat-like React Native app.

For accessibility purposes, I would like to use a physical switch control (accessible under Android settings: Accessibility>Vision>Switch Access>Settings>Assign Keys for Scanning) to navigate "Next" and "Select" UI elements within a React Native app.  I have tried adding "setFocusable" prop to true, but this still does not allow the physical switch to navigate between elements.

When chatting with Android devs, they have suggested establishing a focus chain using android:nextFocusUp and android:nextFocusDown in the layout.  However, since we're constructing the View elements dynamically within the chat app, there is no way to establish this focus chain at build time.

Are there any other approaches other than setFocusable prop to establish a focus chain?

Comment: I have the same problem, I haven't tried this yet but looking to use same concept:
[link](https://github.com/alexcurtis/rn-focalpoint)

Comment: @jatazoulja I am looking at [link](https://github.com/danielweinmann/react-native-stateless-form) to establish a focus chain

Comment: I think the problem there is that it focus only on input fields... not sure with switch.